# Google Analytics track Apache page alias redirect

Tags: string, google-analytics

having to be very simple with this as reputation is too low to be more verbose.
anyway - question:
can GA track an email promotion link that uses Apache to redirect an alias to a real page

Partial from Plesk webspace conf folder vhost.conf file

```
Redirect /getstarted http://lupinedealer.com/content/ez-forms.php
```

Is it possible to use GA to track the amount of traffic this email promotion is generating. Inotherwords can GA track the referer if it's an alias/redirect?

Thanks in advance for any suggstions etc
Peter

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, couldn't you append the campaign parameters to the url in the vhost.conf?

```
Redirect /getstarted http://lupinedealer.com/content/ez-forms.php?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=emailTest
```

Comment: I will look into the use of UTM codes for the email marketing campaigns. Appreciate the heads up.